# Define $\triangle$ as $A\triangle B = (A\cup B - A\cap B )$, show associativity of $\triangle$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We define $\triangle$ as $A\triangle B = (A\cup B - A\cap B )$ and want to prove axiom G1 for the group (G, $\triangle)$.

> We want to show that $(A\triangle B)\triangle C = A\triangle (B\triangle C)$

$(A\triangle B)\triangle C = ((A\cup B - A\cap B)\cup C) - ((A\cup B - A\cap B)\cap C) = $
$(A\cup B \cup C - A \cap B) - ((A\cup B)\cap C) + A\cap B = $

$A\cup B \cup C - (A\cup B)\cap C$

$A\triangle (B\triangle C) = (A\cup (B\cup C - B\cap C)) - (A\cap (B\cup C - B\cap C)) = $
$(A\cup B \cup C - B \cap C) - (A\cap (B\cup C)) + B\cap C = $

$A\cup B \cup C  - (B\cup C)\cap A$

The problem I'm running into now is that I believe that $A\cap (B\cup C) \neq (A\cup B)\cap C$ in general. I'm not sure if I'm taking wrong steps in my derivation (probably). Does anyone know what steps are wrong, or if there's a better way to prove this?

Comment: what's going on with the +? Also it's not clear, but it seems like you're saying $(A \cup B - A \cap B) \cup C =A\cup B \cup C - A\cap B$ which is false.

Comment: A smarter way to prove this is probably the "standard" way to prove that sets are equal: namely, start with "suppose $x \in A \triangle (B \triangle C)$. Then (...), and therefore $x \in (A \triangle B) \triangle C$.

Comment: Hint: prove that $x \in A \triangle B$ if and only if $x$ lies in precisely one of $A$ and $B$. Then prove that $x \in A \triangle (B \triangle C)$ if and only if $x$ lies in an odd number of $A, B, C$.

Comment: I think the easier way to look at this is that $A\triangle B\triangle C$ contains the elements that belong to just one of $A,B,C$.

Comment: You can bet $A \cap (B \cup C) \neq (A \cup B) \cap C$. For example, if $A = \varnothing \neq B \cap C$.

Comment: Note that in the post of which your post is a duplicate, uses the symbol $\oplus$ to designate "symmetric difference".  E.g., $$A \oplus B = (A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B) = (A\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A)$$  So we have that $$A\delta B = (A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B) = (A\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A)$$  Please feel free to how to proceed to prove associativity of $\oplus = \delta$.

Comment: And note that $A-B = A\setminus B = A\cap B^c$, where $B^c$ means the compliment of B: $$x\in (A-B) \iff x\in (A\setminus B) \iff x \in (A\cap B^c) \iff (x\in A \land x\notin B) $$

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference, and correction in my second to last comment prior to this, I meant to write that sometimes $A\Delta B$ is written $A\oplus B$.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a mistake here:

> $((A\cup B - A\cap B)\cup C) - ((A\cup B - A\cap B)\cap C) = $
>   $(A\cup B \cup C - A \cap B) - ((A\cup B)\cap C) + A\cap B = ...$

I am not even exactly sure what you tried to do here, but I assume you tried to go from $((A\cup B - A\cap B)\cup C)$ to $(A\cup B \cup C - A \cap B)$, and from $((A\cup B - A\cap B)\cap C)$ to $((A\cup B)\cap C) + A\cap B$

Now, first of all, there is no set-operator $+$.

Second, I would urge you use use parentheses to avoid any kind of confusion.

So, just focusing on the first term, what you have is:

$$((A\cup B) - (A\cap B))\cup C$$

Now, it looks like you tried some kind of Distribution on this, but you executed that rather poorly.  Here is what you would get if you do Distribution:

$$((A\cup B \cup C) - ((A\cap B)\cup C)$$

However, I wouldn't use Distribution in combination with the setminus operator at all: yes, Distribution of $\cup$ over $-$ happens to work out ok, but Distribution of $\cap$ over $-$ is actually a little weird, since the setminus operator corresponds to a $\cap$ operator itself:

$$A - B =_{df} A \cap B^C$$

Anyway, I recommend using that very identity to rewrite your expressions in terms of $\cap$, $\cup$, and complement, and now you can use all the 'typical' equivalences.

To give you a start:

$$(((A\cup B) - (A\cap B))\cup C) - (((A\cup B) - (A\cap B))\cap C) = $$

$$(((A\cup B) \cap (A\cap B)^C)\cup C) \cap (((A\cup B) \cap (A\cap B)^C)\cap C)^C = $$

$$(((A\cup B) \cap (A^C \cup B^C))\cup C) \cap (((A\cup B) \cap (A\cap B)^C)^C\cup C^C) = ...$$

Yes, it's a slog, but you'll get there eventually!

Comment: I tend to suggest (and abide by) the following:  When you repeat in your post what is wrong, without stating what the correct step following your first expression, if you emphasize *only* what is wrong, without demonstrating what actually follows from the first expression, students to remember what was wrong, but don't necessarily come away with what is right.  Adding that $A-B = A\cap B^c$ isn't terribly informative, either, because they both mean the same thing: $$(x \in A-B) \equiv (x \in A\cap B^c) \equiv (x \in A \land x \notin B)$$

Comment: @amWhy That's good advice, thanks!